# disable or change shortcut of fullscreen mode in Firefox 3.6 due to Firebug shortcut conflict

Tags: firefox, firebug, fullscreen

I am using Firebug with Firefox 3.6 on OSX 10.5.8. Since FF 3.6 there is a shortcut to activate fullscreen mode which is "shift" + "command" + "F". But it is the exact same shortcut of Firebug to launch "Display Element Information".

Since i never and don't really need fullscreen mode and use extensively the "Display Element Information" feature of firebug; i am trying to either change the firebug shortcut or disable the FF shortcut.

I tried finding something when accessing about:config but could not find anything relevant.

Does anybody has a solution or hack?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change FireFox Shortcuts:

There is an extension called KeyConfig that allows you to change the keyboard shortcuts in FireFox. You can find it at the following URL:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=72994

Change FireBug Shortcuts*:

1. Open the FireBug Panel
2. Click the FireBug icon on the top left
3. Select "Customize Shortcuts"
4. Change the shortcuts you want then restart FireFox

*Note:

1. I am using FireBug 1.5
2. I am not sure if the option you want is in the list of shortcuts you need to change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: keyconfig was not compatible with firefox 3.6 when I tried using it. It stopped working at 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortcut you are referring to is actually part of the Web Developer plugin, not Firebug. Firebug has a simliar "Inspect Element" function that uses Ctrl-I.

If you don't want to install yet another plugin, just to change one shortcut, then you will have to change the Web Developer shortcut to something else.

I've tried overriding this behaviour using the OSX System Preferences, creating an Application-only shortcut to the menu item: Tools->Web Developer->CSS->View Style Information, but no dice. This plug-in, while one of the most useful that I've found, has always seemed kind of shoddy. It's rarely updated, and bugs seem to live on forever. It breaks every time FF is updated. etc etc. But I still love it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which extension is causing this for you. Just checked Web Developer Toolbar and don't see Cmd-Shift-F anywhere.

One newer feature in Firebug is the Customize Keyboard Shortcuts preferences panel on the Firebug menu. Open Firebug, click on the Firebug bug icon menu in the top left of the panel and select Customize Keyboard Shortcuts from the menu that shows up. You'll likely need a restart for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now i feel very stupid !!!!

Indeed it is a shortcut from the Web Dev Toolbar and not firebug. I used these 2 so much during a day of work that i forgot they are 2 separate add-ons.

I was able to change the shortcut via the "Options" menu of the Web Dev Toolbar.

And just in case someone changes a shortcut, remember to restart FF for the changes to take effect.

mea culpa.

But thank you every one for helping.

Case closed !